# There's a hidden file with extension .padl in my home directory and I don't know what it's for

Tags: macos, mojave

I saw that someone else asked the same question at superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/1008170/whats-the-498731-padl-file-for but there was no helpful answer so I'm trying here hoping to have more luck.

Like my tag implies, I am not on Windows. I don't share directories over LDAP either.

Edit: Inspecting the file with `plutil -p` gives the following output:

```
{
  "$archiver" => "NSKeyedArchiver"
  "$objects" => [
    0 => "$null"
    1 => {
      "$class" => <CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x7febc05086e0 [0x7fff9011eb60]>{value = 4}
      "NS.keys" => [
        0 => <CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x7febc05085e0 [0x7fff9011eb60]>{value = 2}
      ]
      "NS.objects" => [
        0 => <CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x7febc0508680 [0x7fff9011eb60]>{value = 3}
      ]
    }
    2 => "PaddleT"
    3 => 1563322503.507701
    4 => {
      "$classes" => [
        0 => "NSDictionary"
        1 => "NSObject"
      ]
      "$classname" => "NSDictionary"
    }
  ]
  "$top" => {
    "root" => <CFKeyedArchiverUID 0x7febc05089c0 [0x7fff9011eb60]>{value = 1}
  }
  "$version" => 100000
}
```

Comment: I've always assumed these had something to do with 3rd party apps which I had bought through Paddle, but that's just a guess. They look like generic Apple plist files.

Comment: Can't tell without the actual file, but these usually are temp file generated by Paddle ( https://paddle.com/docs/in-app-introduction/ ).  Paddle is a piece of code indie Mac devs embed into their software to offer trial periods/unlockable registration, and it creates `.padl` files (though usually in /Library/Application Support).  You might have installed some app that uses Paddle to manage product registrations. You can convert it to a more readable format at the command line using `plutil`, but it's most likely a leftover temp file, so there might not be anything interesting in it.

Comment: More details here: https://github.com/PaddleHQ/Mac-Framework/issues/149

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like any hidden files, it’s quite safe to do the following since if you don’t know what it does, the chance even a well intentioned person on the internet knows your setup or needs better than you are low. Better to be safe and free to experiment is my motto.

1. Make a second admin account (assuming you only have this one account). Log out of the current account and be sure you can log in as the new account and restart.
2. Back up the file (if you want)
3. Delete the file

Now you have a line in the sand, escape plan and will know if the file is recreated again the exact date/time it came into existence. What you’re seeing here is a data dump of ObjectiveC data from a program or script.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397048/extract-cfkeyedarchiveruid-value#27338814

Comment: Why would I create a another account?

Comment: @Case39 Say you take my advice and start deleting other files in general. In this case, it’s probably over cautious. In general, it’s mandatory for me. I always have a plan for when my main admin account breaks. Same with backups. I’ll edit my post so this is more clear - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the program that created the file: GPG Suite

In the General Terms of Distribution at https://gpgtools.org/legal

it says:

> 7. Distribution
>    7.1 Our order process is conducted by our online reseller Paddle.com (Seller). Paddle.com is the Merchant of Record for all our orders. Paddle provides all customer service inquiries and handles returns.

Comment: There are many apps that use paddle. On MAC for example Marked 2, iStat Menus, cDock... One way for you to find which ones you may have purchased could be through a search for "paddle" in your saved emails.